# Multiple .py file build in one exe How can i do it in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 file in my project. One is main.py and second is next.py. the button click and open next.py.Normaly it is work. I did no build in one exe. How can do this

How to build file open in button click in exe file and work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyinstaller to turn any python file into an .exe, if next.py is a library for main.py just turn main.py into an exe since the other file isn't needed as an exe for it to work, here is a comprehensive guide on how to do it: https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import subprocess

def open_file():
    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'next.py'], shell=True)
```

and

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Comment: This is not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
main.py
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from tkinter import Tk, Button


def open_next_script():
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # Running as compiled executable
        base_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # Running as Python script
        base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    script_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'next_file.py')

    try:
        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, script_path], startupinfo=startupinfo)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(f"File not found: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")

    root.withdraw()


root = Tk()


# Create a button
button = Button(root, text="Open next.py", command=open_next_script)
button.pack()

# Start the main event loop
root.mainloop()

next.py
from tkinter import Tk, Button

print("Hello")

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()

how to this is convert in one exe and ready to use other computer. I want when the button click in exe and open it
```